# Free list of integers

Tags: c, list, for-loop, free

I was trying to free a list of integers starting from the head and knowing how many elements are in the list, but I am getting an invalid pointer error.
The code is the following:

```
int* factors = job_factorization(number, size);
printf("Thread %d: job terminated. Result: ", params->thread_id);
int* tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++){
    printf("%d ", *factors);
    tmp = factors;
    factors++;
    free(tmp);
}

int *job_factorization(int number, int *size) {
    int *factors;
    int array_size = SIZE_INCREASE;
    int factor = 2;

    if (number < 2)
        return NULL;

    factors = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE_INCREASE);
    *size = 0;

    while (number != 1) {
        // check whether the number is divisible by the factor
        if (number % factor == 0) {
            // if there is no more space available, resize the array
            if (*size == array_size) {
                array_size += SIZE_INCREASE;
                factors = (int *) realloc(factors, sizeof(int) * array_size);
            }
            // add the factor to the list of prime factors
            factors[*size] = factor;
            (*size)++;
            number = number / factor;
        }
        else {
            // if not a factor, move to the next prime number
            factor = next_prime(factor);
        }
    }
    return factors;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea of the reason why this is happening? I have no clue about it (the function job_factorization works correctly)

Comment: This question has been edited such that the accepted answer no longer makes sense, because it depends on knowing about the definition of `job_factorization`, which has been deleted. If you have a different question, start a different answer.

Comment: By removing the `job_factorization` implementation other people with a similar problem will probably not understand it as easily. I think you should put the function back into the question. It was by looking at that function I was able to be sure that my suspicion was correct.

Comment: @Shark44 Without the source code of `job_factorization` your question as well as the answer don't make sense anymore.... I rolled back your last edit.

Comment: Aside: In the first snippet, how is `size` defined, and what memory does it point to? While not necessarily incorrect, `job_factorization(number, size);` looks somewhat atypical with `size` already being a pointer value.  Please be sure to always post a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that nothing is left to mystery (e.g., If `size`  is a pointer value returned by `malloc`, the advice would be that it too needs to be passed to `free`, but if it points to static or automatic storage, this advice is obviously incorrect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`job_factorization` makes one `malloc` (and a number of `realloc`s). To the user of `job_factorization` this looks like one allocation only and that only needs one `free`. Like this:

```
int* factors = job_factorization(number, size);

for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
    printf("%d ", factors[i]);     // don't increase factors in the loop
}

free(factors);                     // one free
```

---

When you use `realloc` it replaces the old allocation, so if you first `malloc` for `1` element, then `realloc` for `2` elements, the result is one allocation with `2` elements - which requires one `free` only.

Comment: It works but I do not really understand the reason behind this, shouldn't the code just free the first element of the list?

Comment: @Shark44 _"It works"_ - Great! _"shouldn't the code just free the first element"_ - No, the allocation is for all elements.

Comment: @Shark44 basically for each value returned by `malloc` and relatives, you need to call `free` exactly once. Calling `free` on anything that hasn't been returned by `malloc` and relatives at some point is wrong. See it as lending money to someone. You lend a 10 dollars to a friend A and 20 dollars to friend B. You expect that at some point B returns 20 dollars to you and not 15 pesos, same for friend A who should return 10 dollars and nothing else.